# Best bookmarking app

Tags: bookmarks

I want to be able to bookmark a page as easily as it is to bookmark using the native browser bookmarking tools. But I want to be able to tag my bookmark or something (maybe pick from a list of folders I have setup) upon bookmarking to keep it organized for later. Then I should be able to log in to some app and view my bookmarks on any computer.

I would prefer this to not be publicly viewable information like I assume social bookmarking sites work. Suggestions?

Comment: @Johhny what kind of browser do you use?

Answer (score 8):

You can secure your bookmarks on [delicious](http://delicious.com) and make them not available for public view. With the delicious extension, I believe you can even organize them into folders.

Another option would be to use [google bookmarks](http://google.com/bookmarks), which pretty much does all that as well.

Comment: Google Bookmarks makes bookmarks appear during search results = killer feature

Answer (score 3):

[diigo](http://www.diigo.com) Is my favourite bookmarking app - the plug-in for chrome is superb!

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Xmarks](http://xmarks.com). Combined with folder organization in Firefox, it will sync your bookmarks across all your computers. There are also options to sync passwords and open browser tabs.

Comment: +1 I combine Xmarks and Delicious, the former for "temporary" links, the latter for important links that i will use for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like [MindiT](http://www.mindit-bookmarking.com) is what you are looking for. It's a personal online bookmark manager that includes a Chrome/ Firefox addon.

The tool includes automatic search tag extraction based on the web page content.  And a lot of other capabilities such as a very nice graphical display, searching, adding notes, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I use [bkmks.com](http://www.bkmks.com/).

- Bookmarking is simple: click a bookmarklet and enter one or more tags.
- Log in from any computer to view all your bookmarks later.
- Your bookmarks are private.

Why I like bkmks.com:

- Ability to graphically organize bookmarks via drag and drop. Bookmarks are grouped by tags. A bookmark may be moved between tags or rearranged within the same tag. You can also drag and drop entire tag groups.
- Fast, uncluttered interface. Most of the page is dedicated to your links with a favicon next to them (optional, but makes visually finding a link much faster).

What I would change about bkmks.com:

- No simple way to delete bookmarks (delete requires two clicks; multiple delete not possible). I fixed this with my own bookmarklet.
- Cannot organize bookmarks into separate tabs. A work-around using multiple accounts is suggested, but it's not very practical.
- Search box is redundant with search from browser address bar; takes up space and captures '/' key when trying to quick find from Opera/Firefox. I fixed this with user JavaScript/custom CSS.
- No way to search/filter bookmarks. Hmm... I might be able to add this with custom user JavaScript.

---

I have [searched for bkmks.com alternatives](https://superuser.com/questions/20526/where-can-i-store-my-private-bookmarks-online-closed) without success, but here are my non-bkmks.com recommendations:

- [Opera Link](http://www.opera.com/link/) synchronized bookmarks work exactly like native browser bookmarks *and* they are synchronized. You can access the bookmarks from other browsers via the Opera Link web interface. I have been using Opera Link synchronized notes with great success.
- [Delicious.com](http://Delicious.com) supports [private bookmarks](https://superuser.com/questions/20526/where-can-i-store-my-private-bookmarks-online/20528#20528).
- Before I found bkmks.com, I used [myhq.com](http://myhq.com) for several years.

Comment: Did you try Google Bookmarks?

Answer (score 0):

I use readitlaterlist.com for things I only want for the next week or so. For frequent sites, I use symbaloo.com as a start/launch page. And if I want to keep it forever I use the scrapbook extension in firefox to save all elements of the page, in case it goes away.

My absolute favorite was illoggo.com, but it died last January.

But, if you really feel like making a huge collection of bookmarks with tags, then delicious. I gave up on delicious. Didn't do it for me. I can't stand the default bookmarking system of browsers, or Google bookmarks. Though I do subscribe to the RSS of my wife's delicious bookmarks, though I rarely look at all the cat videos and recipes. :)

Answer (score 0):

I heavily use  [ReaditLater](http://readitlaterlist.com/).
While not properly a bookmark organizer like delicious it has the following advantages:

- Very easy to bookmark a page (checkmark to click near the browser bar).
- You can tag, group your links
- Syncs with all the browser and the computers you have installed the plugin
- You can log on your account on the web and see your bookmarks on a web page.
- The web app as even a digest function (for subscribers) that will group your tags by interest and make a Newspaper style page for you.
- All your links are private
- Fantastic apps for Iphone and for Ipad that permit to sync (little slow) your linked pages for offline use.
- Very good api and many applications that are using it
- Links to Evernote (another fantastic app)
- Little trick: the offline mode will store all your links in an Sqllite db...then it's up to you to play.

Disclaimer: I'm not in any way related to the developer of the app, just an happy customer.

Comment: Something quite like readitlater would be instapaper. Its just a matter of preference though.

Comment: I think this is best used in combination with a separate bookmarking app

Answer (score 0):

Use ReadItLater which is available for FireFox, Chrome and also iPhone app and could also be used online for the websites bookmarked !!

Answer (score 0):

You can try http://lstack.com/ - all LStack bookmarks are private by default. Regarding organization of bookmarks, in LStack you can assign arbitrary tags and parameters (in form of key and value).

Comment: Are you affiliated with lstack.com? If so, you should disclose it.